# Stream closed with status: Status{code=NOT_FOUND, description=No document to update: projects/*/123, cause=null}

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know why it's giving this error and also not updating the data in firestore.

```
                                          FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                          .collection('extra')
                                          .doc(widget.extraName)
                                          .update(
                                        {
                                          'subExtra':
                                              FieldValue.arrayUnion([
                                            {
                                              'name':
                                                  _subNameTextController
                                                      .text,
                                            }
                                          ])
                                        },
                                      );
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to call `update` on a document, that document has to exist already. The error message indicates that no document with the `widget.extraName` name was found in the `extra` collection.

---

If the document indeed isn't supposed to exist yet, you call `set` (instead of `update`) to create it with the data you specify.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('extra')
  .doc(widget.extraName)
  .set({ ... }); //
```

---

If the document may or may not exist yet, you can call `set` with merge options specifying that you want to merge the data into the existing document if that already exists, or create the document with the specified data otherwise. So:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('extra')
  .doc(widget.extraName)
  .set({ ... }, SetOptions(merge: true)); //
```

Comment: Sir, I tried this before, but it makes a new document instead of updating it.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I got it where I am wrong.